# ES6 destructuring to get the nth item from inner array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring

I have an array in my state in my React project. something like :

```
state = {
   cats : [
      {cid : 1 , value : 1}
      {cid : 2 , value : 3}
      {cid : 3 , value : 4}
   ],
   curpage : 3
}
```

now all I want is to get `nth item` of the array `cats` with destructring. I tried

```
const { cat : {cats[id]} } = this.state;
```

or

```
 const { cats[id] } = this.state;
```

Comment: `nth item` Do you mean the item at index `id`?

Comment: yes, that's what I meant

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the [computed object property with destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Computed_object_property_names_and_destructuring) to get the `n`th array item and assign it to a variable:

```js
const state = {
   cats : [
      {cid : 1 , value : 1},
      {cid : 2 , value : 3},
      {cid : 3 , value : 4}
   ],
   curpage : 3
}

const n = 2;

const { cats: { [n]: nthCat} } = state;

console.log(nthCat)
```

Or, if `n` is small and you know it beforehand, you could [ignore the values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Ignoring_some_returned_values) you don't need:

```js
const state = {
   cats : [
      {cid : 1 , value : 1},
      {cid : 2 , value : 3},
      {cid : 3 , value : 4}
   ],
   curpage : 3
}

const { cats: [,,thirdCat] } = state;

console.log(thirdCat)
```

Answer (score 4):

You could destructure to the index and take a renamed value.

```js
var state = { cats: [{ cid: 1, value: 1 }, { cid: 2, value: 3 }, { cid: 3, value: 4 }], curpage: 3 },
    index = 2,
    { cats: { [index]: item } } = state;

console.log(item);
```

Answer (score 0):

> let nthID = 1; let {cats} = state; let nthChild = cats[nthID];